# Selenium create multiple browser sessions

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I want to create multiple browser session and login with different accounts. If I use the code below it makes what I want but close all browser after the for loop ends. My guess is that python ends all processes after the focus is gone. How can I solve the problem? With multithreading?
I want that every session to stay open for 60 seconds.

```
def playroutine():
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(getlogindata())):
        username, password = givemelogin(index)
        index += 1
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/fb/Documents/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
        driver.get('[...]')
        driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_id("login-button").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.get('[...]')
```

Thanks :)

Comment: you'll need a separate object for each driver, no?  You are creating all as "driver".

Answer (score 0):

You can't close **all** browsers after your loop ends, because the `driver` variable only exists in the context of your `for` loop.

You can however, close the drivers inside the loop, one at a time:

```
def playroutine():
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(getlogindata())):
        username, password = givemelogin(index)
        index += 1
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/fb/Documents/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
        driver.get('[...]')
        driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_id("login-button").click()
        time.sleep(2)

        # close the driver
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
```

Or, you can keep track of the drivers in a list, and try to loop through them and close them -- this is a bit hacky, and I can't say I would recommend it:

```
def playroutine():

    driver_list = []
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(getlogindata())):
        username, password = givemelogin(index)
        index += 1
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/fb/Documents/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.

        # add this driver to your list to keep track of it
        driver_list.append(driver)

        driver.get('[...]')
        driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(username)
        driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
        driver.find_element_by_id("login-button").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.get('[...]')

    # for loop is finished -- close all drivers
    for driver in driver_list:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
```